# Being stupid.. Why can't node.js/node find the path? It's an existing path

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Error:
Error: Cannot find module 'PATH'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Comment: Where's your code? Unclear what's causing the error.

Comment: It's just an internal node error.

Comment: Even if its just an internal node error, you have posted a question on Stack overflow already, post the code with the errors and what fix you did to make it work so it can help others in the future

Comment: @web_walkerX This is my first question and I didn't find a solution?

Comment: There a lot of uncertainties surrounding your question Max, Is PATH an npm package you installed?, is it a custom module you wrote yourself? and we certainly can't be sure till you make your question as clear as possible. Post the code causing the error or a few screenshots that will point us in the right direction and you will definitely get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am guessing correctly though, You are trying to reference `PATH` from another file, probably your entry file and it can't find `PATH`. Try one or all of the following:

If `PATH` is a directory, Use `dirname` to point to the directory corretly

e.g `const Path = path.join(__dirname, '../templates/path')`

If `PATH` is a file you are trying to reference, make sure the last line in `PATH.js` is `module.exports = path` then use `const PATH = require('./path/to/file')` to reference it